# How to set autocomplete text in android fragment

Tags: java, android

I want to set autocomplete text in my application.. I did some coding but i got an error and my application stopped unfortunately. Please anyone fix that.

My code here:

Addressfragment.java

```js
package com.h2o;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
public class AddressFragment extends Fragment {

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_address, container,false);

  // Get a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView in the layout
  AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_autoCompleteTextView);
  // Get the string array
  String[] city = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.city);
  // Create the adapter and set it to the AutoCompleteTextView
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>((MainActivity) getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city);

  textView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```js
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.h2o, PID: 2158
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.h2o/com.h2o.AccountActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.h2o.AccountActivity cannot be cast to com.h2o.MainActivity
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.h2o.AccountActivity cannot be cast to com.h2o.MainActivity
            at com.h2o.AddressFragment.onCreateView(AddressFragment.java:53)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5953)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I think, In the above code(Addressfragment.java) this line an error

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter((MainActivity) getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city);

Please anyone help me!

Thanks for advance..

Answer (score 1):

Change this

`ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter((MainActivity) getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city);`

to

`ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city);`

Comment: and if it still gives error, cast the activity ..(AccountActivity) getActivity(),,,

Comment: Ok then try cast getActivity with (AccountActivity). Like `ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter((AccountActivity) getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city);`